# How to prevent legend being truncated in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh, legend

Here's a short Python3 script that draws a bunch of sine waves with bokeh (2.2.1).

```
import numpy
import bokeh.models
import bokeh.plotting

x    = numpy.linspace(0, 4*numpy.pi, 100)
sinx = numpy.sin(x)

bokeh.plotting.output_file("truncatedlegend.html")

plot = bokeh.plotting.figure(toolbar_location="above")

glyphs = [ plot.line(x, (1 + i/20)*sinx, line_width=2) for i in range(41) ]

legend = bokeh.models.Legend(
    items=[
        ("%.2f*sin(x)" % ((1 + i/20)), [ glyphs[i] ]) for i in range(41)
    ]
)

plot.add_layout(legend, 'right')

bokeh.plotting.show(plot)
```

The legend should have 40 entries, but there's only space for 24 of them, so the rest are thrown away. I tried changing the margin of the plot,

```
    margin = plot.margin
    plot.margin = (margin[0], margin[1], margin[2] + 600, margin[3])
```

and it did increase the available space (in that a second plot (not shown), moves down)---but the legend doesn't expand into the available space.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Since bokeh version [3.1.0](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/12687) it is possible to have a gird layout in the legend. This means, you have to pass the number of columns (`ncols`) or the number of rows (`nrows`) to the Legend.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

x    = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
sinx = np.sin(x)

p = figure(toolbar_location="above")
glyphs = [p.line(x, (1 + i/20)*sinx, line_width=2) for i in range(40)]
legend = Legend(
    items=[(f"{1+i/20:.2f}*sin(x)", [g]) for i, g in enumerate(glyphs)],
    ncols=2,
)
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')
show(p)
```

[image: legend with two columns]

---

### Older answer

This is an issue of some other questions on SO I have seen before. The consense was to add more than one legend.

**Output**

[image: two legends will do]

**Your Example**

```
import numpy
import bokeh.models
import bokeh.plotting

x    = numpy.linspace(0, 4*numpy.pi, 100)
sinx = numpy.sin(x)

bokeh.plotting.output_file("truncatedlegend.html")

plot = bokeh.plotting.figure(toolbar_location="above")
glyphs = [ plot.line(x, (1 + i/20)*sinx, line_width=2) for i in range(41) ]

legend1 = bokeh.models.Legend(
    items=[("%.2f*sin(x)" % ((1 + i/20)), [ glyphs[i] ]) for i in range(23)]
)
legend2 = bokeh.models.Legend(
    items=[("%.2f*sin(x)" % ((1 + i/20)), [ glyphs[i] ]) for i in range(23,41)]
)

plot.add_layout(legend1, 'right')
plot.add_layout(legend2, 'right')
bokeh.plotting.show(plot)
```

Right now I don't find the old posts on SO. But there is an open feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3880) where this solution is mentioned.

Comment: This is a great workaround, so I've liked it. I won't accept it as the answer, in case in a few months the feature request is fulfilled, and it becomes possible to somehow expand the bounding box within which the legend is clipped so that it can be seen in its entirety. But it certainly gets me on my way, so thanks for that!

Comment: Another comment in case someone comes by. In one case, I added 24 legends to a graph, and the whole graph disappeared. This seems to be because the legends take up space in the graph's domain, and it has to shrink to let the legend fit. Once it shrinks beyond a certain point, the whole thing (graph + legends) disappears entirely. The solution was to add an arbitrary number (determined by experiment) to the graph width, like this:
```
 plot.plot_width = w
```
I found 10000 was big enough in the case I mentioned.